# How to read data from KML on Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

I use the Google Maps Javascript API to show a map with a KML layer. I am looking for a way to read the data/features of that KML and process them in another section of the page. I can only find a sample to read a feature per click but not for all features. how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I've found for handling KML gracefully and having all the features you wish to use is [GeoXML3](https://github.com/geocodezip/geoxml3).  The author @geocodezip is a member of Stack Overflow and helps with questions.  Also consult the [Geocodezip.com site](http://www.geocodezip.com/) for lots of Google Maps API examples.  You might also want to see the discussion for [question 44526365](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44529548/90647).